# How do I resolve Firebase Auth Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appVerificationDisabledForTesting')

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, vite

I cannot currently instantiate a new RecaptchaVerifier. I am running the parent Sign-In page on a Vite dev server connected to the Firebase emulator suite. Current firebase version in package.json is 10.8.0.

// firebaseModular.js

```
const mainConfig = {
  apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: import.meta.env.VITE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.VITE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: import.meta.env.VITE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

export const firebaseApp = initializeApp(mainConfig, "modular");
export const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
getAuth(firebaseApp).settings.appVerificationDisabledForTesting = true;
// auth.settings.appVerificationDisabledForTesting = true;
```

// SignInForm.js

```
import { auth } from "../../constants/firebaseModular";
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword, RecaptchaVerifier } from "firebase/auth";

const SignInForm = () => {
  ...
  console.log("auth settings in SignInForm", auth.settings);

  const recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
    "recaptcha-container",
    auth
```

Additional notes:

- I've already seen the discussion about the argument order. If the auth instance is in the final position, I get the above error. If it is in the first position, as many have suggested I get `Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error).`
- The console.log above logs the object `{appVerificationDisabledForTesting: true}` at runtime.
- Both active and commented out approaches to setting the value to true in firebaseModular.js produce the same logs and errors.

UPDATE
Attempted @Rainy sidewalks solution removing all related code from firebaseModular.js and updating SignInForm.jsx as follows:

```
import { auth, firebaseApp } from "../../constants/firebaseModular";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const SignInForm = () => {
 ...

  console.log("auth settings in SignInForm before", auth.settings);
  getAuth(firebaseApp).settings.appVerificationDisabledForTesting = true;
  console.log("auth settings in SignInForm after", auth.settings);
  const recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
    "recaptcha-container",
    getAuth(firebaseApp)
  );
```

Comment: can you post full code of SignInForm.js specially  of `SignInForm`

Answer (score 0):

if you look in to [phone-auth#integration-testing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#integration-testing)
here you see that you should pass the firebase auth instance's settings through the getAuth function directly.

so try this

```
  // firebaseModular.js

const mainConfig = {
  apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: import.meta.env.VITE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.VITE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: import.meta.env.VITE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(mainConfig,);
export const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

export default firebaseApp;
```

and in the SignInForm.js

```
// SignInForm.js

import { firebaseApp } from "../../constants/firebaseModular";
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword, RecaptchaVerifier } from "firebase/auth";//import { getAuth, signInWithPhoneNumber } from "firebase/auth";


const SignInForm = async () => {
  
  const authInstance = await getAuth();
  authInstance.settings.appVerificationDisabledForTesting = true;
  console.log("auth settings in SignInForm", authInstance.settings+':here with :'+ authInstance.settings.appVerificationDisabledForTesting);


  //var appVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container'); Web modular API style

  const recaptchaVerifier = new authInstance.RecaptchaVerifier("recaptcha-container");

  //other as you need from here

};
```

try and let me know

Comment: I wasn't exporting getAuth() from my firebase file, so I'm assuming you meant to import from 'firebase/auth' package. I imported the firebaseApp into the form and called the functions as you suggested, but unfortunately the error persists. I can also log it here (initially true) set it to false and it correctly logs after the change.

Comment: i just notice why did you pass the `"modular"` to initializeApp ?try the edit i think rest is ok.

Comment: It's a leftover from upgrading from v7. Removing it makes no difference.

Comment: what firebase version you are using ?

Comment: Error was happening on 10.5.0 (I saw that version referenced in another SO post) so I upgraded to 10.8.0

Comment: exactly that i was thinking .